# Using Rolle’s Theorem prove that the cubic equation $x^3+ax+b$ has at most one root

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, roots, rolles-theorem

A brief explanation of Rolle’s Theorem would be appreciated! I understand that it is a special case of the mean value theorem but I am not sure how to apply it to this question.

**Edit:** $a>0$

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that a condition is that a>0

Comment: By Rolle, the derivative must vanish at some point between two roots. However, the derivative is $3x^2+a\geq a>0$.

Comment: Do you mean "has at most one real zero"? There is no "equation" in question or title.

Comment: @OscarRascal if you would write that up as an answer, I would be happy to upvote it :) and so would a bunch of others. You posted the comment way before the current answer got posted...

Comment: @gt6989b [Right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517149/spectral-properties-of-compact-operators#comment7233433_3517149) ... I don't care about votes, even less yours.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x^3+ax+b$. If $f(x)=0$ had two distinct solutions $x$ and $x'$, with $x<x'$, then you would have $f'(y)=0$ for some $y\in(x,x')$. But that cannot happen, since $f'(y)=3y^2+a>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Rolle's Theorem says:

If a function $f(x)$ is

1. Continuous in the interval  $\left[ a, b \right]$
2. Differentiable in the interval $\left( a, b \right)$
3. And if $f(a)=f(b)$,

then there exists one point c between a and b for which $f'(c)=0$

We can interpret this geometrically:
The point c lying between a and b is where the tangent to the graph of $f(x)$ is parallel to th $x$ axis